# Find key in file

Tags: python, file

There is a file that stores the keys in the form of numbers. For example:

```
81
35
1
56
129
```

After that, the cycle starts from 0 and up to the given limits.
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6....

Help, how to check each variant from the cycle for the presence in the file? If there is such a number in the file on a separate line, then output it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to clarify your question. What is the 'cycle'? What do you mean by 'the given limits'? What are the keys? Can you illustrate by showing more of your file and the code you have tried to write?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
fhandle = open('keys.txt')

# Generate dict of all the keys from the file
key_dict = dict()
for key in fhandle:
    key_dict[int(key)] = key

limit = int(input("Enter search limit: "))
key_found = 0
for i in range(limit):
    search_key = key_dict.get(i, False)
    if search_key:
        print('Key found for: ', i)
        key_found += 1

print('Total Keys found: ', key_found)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).